# highlight or add class to parent li element in click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I am learning jquery and css.
I have menu items which look like this. You can see css,html, jquery here http://jsfiddle.net/rZR2Y/

```
html
<div id="nav"> 
    <ul>    
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Blog1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

jquery
$( document ).ready( function() {
   $( '#nav > ul > li' ).click( function() {
      $( '#nav > ul' ).children('li').removeClass();
      $( this ).addClass( 'selected' );
   });
   $( '#nav > ul > li > ul > li' ).click( function() {
      $( '#nav > ul' ).children('li').removeClass();
      $( this ).parent('li').addClass( 'selected' );
   });
});

css
    #nav .selected a{background:red;display:block}
```

What I would like to have is, when I click sub li items ie Home1/home2/home3, then parent li ie Home should be highlighted.

I am doing something wrong in selector selection. Also, any other better solutions are also welcome.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** 
I am sorry, my original markup was wrong. Closing sub li should naturally come after all submenu items. 
Does this now change all jquery ?

Thanks for your answers.
I would very much appreciate some explanation, so that I also learn what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE2:**
After updating my markup, and also css like this

```
    #nav .selected  > a{background:red;display:block}
```

even my original solution works. Just learnt few css and jquery stuffs. Thanks everyone.
Updated fiddle with updated markup and css and original jquery is here 
http://jsfiddle.net/rZR2Y/26/

Comment: @Yoshi I have now added all code here.

Comment: On a side note: Your markup is incorrect. The closing `<li>`s should come after the nested `<ul>`s. ;)

Comment: Oh, yes I show that one now. Now when I change as you said, then my whole query selection is changed.

Comment: Could be that selectors needed changing. But in general I think your selectors are to complicated for such a simple task. (I added an answer using only simple selectors)

Answer (score 2):

Your selector for sub-level `li` elements was incorrect, it should be `#nav > ul > ul > li`.

Try this:

```
 $( document ).ready( function() {
     $( '#nav > ul > li' ).click( function() {
         $( '#nav > ul' ).children('li').removeClass();
         $( this ).addClass( 'selected' );
     });
     $( '#nav > ul > ul > li' ).click( function() {
         $( '#nav > ul' ).children('li').removeClass();
         $( this ).parent('ul').prev().addClass( 'selected' );
     });
 });
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/rZR2Y/3/)**

Comment: thanks it worked. But can you please explain why it should be #nav > ul > ul > li and not #nav > ul > li > ul > li. I thougt I have to write all elements in order, they are there. But why we need to skip top li in selection.

Comment: Your second level `ul` is not contained within an `li`.

Answer (score 2):

Given your code, you could use:

```
$('#nav').on('click', 'li', function () {
  $('#nav li').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).parentsUntil('#nav', 'li').add(this).addClass('selected');
  return false;
});
```

Though I have my doubts that this is what you're looking for. Maybe try also changing your css to:

```
#nav .selected > a{background:red;display:block}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F8dbG/2/

*updated* using a the additional selector for `on` to reduce number of event bindings. (thanks @diEcho)

Comment: better way : `$('#nav ul').on('click','li', function () {`

Comment: but didn't get what `.add(this)` do

Comment: @diEcho Because I'm using `parentsUntil`, the clicked `li` would not receive the `.selected` class without it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
 $( document ).ready( function() {
     $( 'li' ).click( function() {
         $( 'li').removeClass('selected' );
         var $this = $( this );
         $this.addClass( 'selected' );
         $this.parent().prev().addClass( 'selected' );
     });
 });
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rZR2Y/22/